# Is it possible to disable multiple row selection in a Dynamics 365 view?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-365

As the title says, is there a way? The reason I need this, is because I created a custom entity view for editing records. I'd like the user to only choose one row at a time. (This means, that bulk editing is not allowed for the user at this particular entity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot disable multiselect functionality.

But you can do some workaround using Ribbon button Enable rule - `SelectionCountRule`. [Read more](https://d365demystified.com/2020/03/06/show-ribbon-button-only-on-record-selection-in-dynamics-crm/)

Set both Minimum and Maximum as 1 for your need.

[image]

Another option is using custom Enable rule by checking `SelectedControlAllItemIds` to see the count of selected records. [Read more](https://pravinpawarweb.wordpress.com/2019/07/15/hide-ribbon-button-on-view-home-grid-if-one-or-more-records-selected-in-view/)